# Multiple insert statements in single ODBC ExecuteNonQuery (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I'm inserting multiple rows into a DB, and joining them together in an attempt to improve performance.
I get an ODBCException telling me my SQL syntax is wrong. But when I try it in the mysql commandline client, it works just fine..
I ran a simplified test to describe the process.

Command Line Client:

```
mysql> create table test (`id` int, `name` text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES ('1', 'Foo');INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES ('2', 'bar');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

After that I ran this code on the same DB:

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES ('1', 'Foo');INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES ('2', 'bar');";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

which gives me the following error:

```
+       base    {"ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES ('2', 'bar')' at line 1"} System.Data.Common.DbException {System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Yes, ODBC does NOT support batch processing.</s> (EDIT: See @Jean-Do's answer for a more up to date solution.)

But there is another option:

1. Use the [MySQL .NET Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) instead of ODBC.
2. Then use the MySQL alternative INSERT statement: `INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES ('1', 'Foo'), ('2', 'bar');`.

Comment: @RobertPenridge The only thing currently wrong is the first phrase, and it *was* right at the time it was written (2010).

Answer (score 15):

Batching is actually supported by MySQL ODBC driver v5+, you just need to click on the Details button of the ODBC control panel (if on Windows) and check the "Allow multiple statements" checkbox.

Alternatively, uses OPTIONS=67108864 on you odbc connection string.

More information here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html

Comment: This saved my ass, but just a small correction, I found it is 'option' with no 's', i.e. option=67108864; Also an updated link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

It cannot handle batching (using ; to separate multiple statements) since this would require two way communication. I am afraid you have to do it in a loop and go to database multiple times.

In fact I have never been able to use batching with any managed provider.