# Can't get LAST_INSERT_ID() to work from ASP classic

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

This question is driving me crazy and I hope you can help. I want to use the following sql for a MySQL-database:

```
INSERT INTO Prenumeranter (Pren_Namn,Pren_Email) values ('Testing','test@test.com');  
UPDATE Prenumeranter SET Pren_kod = encrypt(LAST_INSERT_ID()) WHERE Pren_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This code works perfect if I run it in PhpMyAdmin but if I run it on my asp classic page it only gives errors for the LAST_INSERT_ID(). I have tried to rewrite it in different ways, but they all work in PhpMyAdmin but not from the asp page. The error message is:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.30-cll-lve]You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE Prenumeranter
>   SET Pren_kod = encrypt(LAST_INSERT_ID()) WHERE Pren_id = LA' at line 1
>
> /sida.asp, line 122

If I replace the LAST_INSERT_ID with an int value ('85' or something) everything works fine from asp page too so it must be a problem with the LAST_INSERT_ID().

I appreciate all help that can get me back on track...

Comment: That's 2 separate queries. phpMyAdmin is either executing them separately or instructing MySQL to expect multiple statements.  Execute them individually or consult the odbc docs to see if it supports multiple statements with MySQL.

Comment: check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144961/multiple-insert-statements-in-single-odbc-executenonquery-c and the second answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I change from OPTION=3 to OPTION=67108867 in the connection and it all works fine now. :)