# Classic ASP Multiple Statments Last ID Doesnt Work

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

i have a multiple statments code like below.

```
Set db = Server.createObject("Adodb.Connection")
db.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};option=67108864; SERVER=" & mysql_server & "; UID=" & mysql_user & "; pwd=" & mysql_pass & "; db=" & mysql_db & ";"
set rss=db.execute("INSERT INTO boardlar (baslik, hesap_id) VALUES ('Deneme','1');select LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastid from boardlar")

response.write rss("lastid")
```

i checked it on phpmyadmin and it works. But in asp or php it didnt work.

it says not exixts no field from query. how can i resolve it?

Comment: Does [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061238/cant-get-last-insert-id-to-work-from-asp-classic#comment28180883_19061238) on an existing question help?

Comment: Try adjusting the `OPTION` flags to `67108867` which is a combination of `FIELD_LENGTH`: "Do not Optimize Column Width",
`FOUND_ROWS`: "Return Matching Rows" and `MULTI_STATEMENTS`: "Support multiple sql statements in a batch".

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50095273/692942) helpful?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to do with the combination of `OPTION` flags as these can be combined. The general consensus is to have the following three flags;

1. `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH` (1) - "Do not optimize Column Width" <sup>1</sup>
2. `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` (2) - "Return matching rows"
3. `FLAG_MULT_STATEMENTS` (67108864) - "Support multiple SQL statements in a batch"

When these values are combined the `OPTION` parameter value becomes `67108867`.

Which means a simple change to;

```vb
db.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};option=67108867; SERVER=" & mysql_server & "; UID=" & mysql_user & "; pwd=" & mysql_pass & "; db=" & mysql_db & ";"
```

---

<sup>1. The `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH` [has been depreciated](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35044) from the ODBC connector GUI since version 3.51.18</sup>

#### Another solution

It does seem that it's the lack of `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` in the `OPTION` parameters that causes this particular problem but as a quick test you could see if you can access the query result via an ordinal field without using the alias, something like this;

```vb
<%
'Assumed declarations, not setting server, user and pass as you will have these defined.
Dim db, res, mysql_server, mysql_user, mysql_pass

Set db = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
db.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};option=67108864; SERVER=" & mysql_server & "; UID=" & mysql_user & "; pwd=" & mysql_pass & "; db=" & mysql_db & ";"
Set rss=db.execute("INSERT INTO boardlar (baslik, hesap_id) VALUES ('Deneme','1');select LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastid from boardlar")

'Use ordinal positioning instead of field alias to return the value.
Call Response.Write(rss(0))
%>
```

---

#### Useful links

- [Answer to MySQL ODBC configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50095489/692942)
- [What's the Option=N in the MySQL ODBC connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407898/692942)