# ASP MYSQL error with Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement. Tried everywhere

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

This is my code, and i need to add alot more lines, im testing with just two

```
' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ")"
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")
```

i keep getting the error " Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.". i add semicolons, and i get "expected end of statement"

below i will post all ways i tried the semicolon. i dont know what else to do.

```
' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ");"
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")

' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ")";
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")

' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ";)"
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")

' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ")"
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp");

' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ")";"
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")

' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ");";
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")
```

And my frustrated trial:

```
' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & "),(" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,2,'" &ps12& "', " & pg12 & ", " & pp12 & ")";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")
```

every way fails every time. i either get missing semicolon or expected end of statement

Comment: check if this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15440056/1682881

Answer (score 0):

When inserting into MYSQL you need single quotes around the values that you are inserting. Try adding them before and after your double quotes surrounding your variable names, for example

```
('" & pschedid & "',
```

If single quotes don't work try backticks. MYSQL is kind of weird about it's quotes, if you type queries into Word using single quotes and copy paste it won't work, but if you do it on notepad it works.