# Execute multiple SQL statements with ODBC

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I'm new to `ODBC`, and I'm finding it difficult to do what I would immagine to be a simple thing.

I have some simple `SQL` scripts, and I'm trying to run them using `ODBC`, using this `C#` method I've written:

```
public static int ExecuteSqlNonQuery(string sql, string connectionString)
{
    int result = 0;
    using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above method works if the sql script I pass in only has **one** statement, like for example:

```
update sakila.customer set first_name = now() where customer_id = 1;
```

but if it has multiple statements, like for example:

```
update sakila.customer set first_name = now() where customer_id = 1; 
update sakila.customer set first_name = now() where customer_id = 2;
```

then the query will fail, telling me that everything after the first statement is invalid:

```
ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.19-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update sakila.customer set first_name = now() where customer_id = 2' at line 1
```

So... how do I execute a piece of SQL with multiple statements using ODBC? I know that a quick workaround would be to just split the string into lines and run them one at the time, but that feels "hacky" to me... there must be a "proper" way to do it... right?

**EDIT - just in case someone has the same problem:**
The accepted answer in the question marked as duplicate of this (saying this cannot be done) is incorrect. The second non-accepted answer below it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440056/300741
worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Can you explain why do you use ODBC when a native NET ADO provider exists for MySql that certainly supports batched statement like these?

Comment: I don't know if this is still true, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144961/multiple-insert-statements-in-single-odbc-executenonquery-c

Comment: @Steve: because our app uses ODBC to interface with multiple backend databases and we don't know before hand what DB will be used, the user selects it from the available ODBC data sources... it's how the app works and I cannot change that.

However, the question you linked contained the correct answer! NOT the accepted one, but the one below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440056/300741
Flagging the option it mentioned worked! +1

Comment: Well, that's good to know +1 also from me.